# Где реализовывать логику получения информации по апи и сохранение в дб

Tags: android, ооп, kotlin, архитектура, solid

Например, у нас есть 2 источника данных(DataSource). Когда получаем данные из апи, их нужно проверить. И если проверка прошла успешна, выполнить еще 1 api запрос и сохранить данные в бд.

Вопрос в чем. Где реализовывать эту логику?
У меня есть несколько догадок, и я хочу точно знать где я должен это делать.

---

`1 -` В data слое(в каком-то методе репозитория, делать первый запрос, проверять, делать второй и отправлять результат в бд)? **Т.е выходит 1 метод в репозитории, где нужные проверки и решения происходят**

Если вы не поняли что я имею ввиду, вот пример

```
class SomeUseCase(private val repository: Repository): Boolean {
   fun signIn(){
       return repository.signIn()
   }
}

class SomeRepositoryImpl(val apiDataSource: Api, val dbDataSource: Db): Repository {
    fun signIn(): Boolean {
      val hasApiKey = apiDataSource.HasApiKey()

       if(!hasApiKey) {
            val apiKey = apiDataSource.GetApiKey()
            dbDataSource.addApiKeyToDb(apiKey)

            return true;
       }

       return false;
    }
}
```

---

`2-` Или создавать методы в репозитории(на отправку второго запроса и добавление в бд).

Получается, что будет метод отправки первого запроса в репозитории, проверка в `usecase` если все норм, вызов из `usecase` второго запроса и вызов 3его(добавление в бд)?
(этот вариант кажется нелогичным, ибо в репозитории дохера не нужных методов получится, но все же есть сомнение)

Если вы не поняли вдруг, вот пример `usecase`

```
class SomeUseCase(private val repository: Repository): Boolean{
   fun signIn(){
       val hasApiKey = repository.HasApiKey()

       if(!hasApiKey) {
            val apiKey = repository.GetApiKey()
            repository.addApiKeyToDb(apiKey)

            return true;
       }

       return false;
   }
}
```

Какой из этих способов правильный. И вообще есть ли правильный среди них?

Comment: Начните с того, что сформулируйте требование, которое будет реализовано этим кодом. Мне из вопроса оно не очень понятно, так как вы говорите о деталях реализации, а вот само требование, от меня по крайней мере, ускользает. Вообще, реализация требования в репозитории выглядит не очень хорошо, но чтоб сказать точнее нужно понимать, что это за требование. Подумайте об ответственностях классов. Репозиторий - это хранилище, в нем нет логики. Но может у вас другое разделение обязанностей, если это так , то нужно в вопросе упомянуть.

Comment: Если вы про бизнес логику. У меня стоит сейчас задача сделать регистрацию и авторизацию. На сервере у меня стоит oauth2(т.е мне нужен токен для клиента). При регистрации и авторизации я хочу проверять, есть ли у приложения токен(и если есть, действительный ли он). Если нет, то обновить и завершить регистрацию или авторизацию

Comment: Переписал комментарий. Дело в том, что я не понимаю где должна быть эта логика(по проверке токена и его обновлении). В репозитории эта проверка мне кажется уместной. Так как домейн не знает о реализации даты и все что ему нужно знать, что есть такой-то метод, который регистрирует и авторизирует. А в дате уже логика по получению токена и регистрации или авторизации. Но я новичок в этом, поэтому не уверен что это так. И хочу узнать, где мне писать подобные проверки. Может мне вообще нужно написать отдельный репозиторий по проверке и обновлении токена. И в юзкейсе использовать 2 репозитория

Comment: Авторизация это вообще отдельная вещь, это crosscuting concern (по русски наверно правильно перевести как "пронизывающий аспект"), т.е. это касается всех абсолютно сценариев, а значит рассматривать нужно это отдельно. Логика проверки авторизован ли пользователь, как это делается, что делать если нет - это где-то будет, но точно не на уровне основной бизнес логики и основной домен тут ни при чем. Что касается уместности логики в репозитории, опять же, возвращаемся к вопросу ответственности. За что отвечает репозиторий? Хранение? Тогда знание о том, когда и можно ли добавлять ключ, там лишнее.

Comment: Он отвечает за регистрацию и авторизацию. Т.е отправление запроса на апи и получение ответа. Но мне нужно еще и токен проверять(он берется из бд, если он там есть). Можно ли токен использовать или нужно отправить запрос и обновить токен(а потом записать его в бд). Сейчас это все у меня сделано в одном репозитории, в котором есть методы signUp и signIn. Т.е он отвечает за авторизацию(отправление запросов)

Comment: Из этого описани единственное, что странно, это название, а в остальном выглядит ок. Если бы это был не репозиторий, а сервис, то у меня вопросов бы не было, и самое место всей этой логике в сервисе.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135434/discussion-between-gorge-flow-and-roman-stop-ru-aggression-in-ua).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

по одно из трактовок юзкейса - он не должен обладать логикой, а должен быть лишь связующим звеном между слоями Data и UI  (которые в идеальнйо чистой архитектуре не знают друг про друга, но оба знают про ЮзКейс).
лично я всегда в голове пользуюсь правилом: "если я не могу заменить юзкейс опциональной переменной - это плохой юзкейс".

мне нравится 1ый вариант, потому что:

1. у вас есть DataSource, которые занимаются всей "грязной" работой.
2. репозиторий - это начальник, который координирует их работу.
3. ЮзКейс - просто связующее звено.

Comment: Спасибо, мне тоже так кажется, но я нашел 1 ньюанс. Если вас не затруднит, можете пожалуйста просвятить.

Comment: Эта логика, которая находится в репозитории, будет использоваться и в других репозиториях. Значит, её логично вынести в `DataSource`, который отвечает за получение свежего `apikey`(в нем будет логика по проверкам и сохранениям и доп вызовам апи). Как мне вынести это в отдельный(общий) `DataSource`, если у меня уже есть 2 `DataSource`(по получению токена и сохранению его). Могу ли я в общий DataSource, в конструктор передать эти 2 дата сурса и там сделать из них более сложные проверки. Чтобы не загрязнять репозиторий и использовать его в других репозиториях?

Comment: Я бы мог сделать так. Но меня смущает, что у меня `DataSourcы` будут в одном общем `DataSource`. Если я так делаю, значит я не должен эти 2 класса называть `DataSource` или все же они могут так называться и быть имплементированы в общий `DataSource`?

Comment: это уже начинается полемика и демогагия. я скажу что лично я думаю (хотя и часто встречаюсь с хейтом этого). DataSource - отвечают за получение/сохранение "чистых" данных. Репозитории - за логику последовательности действи DataSours'ов. Репозиторий МОЖЕТ включать в себя ДРУГИЕ репозитории.

Comment: с точки зрения логики, чем больше у вас раздробленных классов, где каждый выполлняет 1 отвечающую ему логику - тем лучше. вы можете назвать класс, который будет отвечать за логику 2 ДатаСорсов как угодно. это может быть и DataSource и Репозиторий или можете внести такое понятия как Менеджер в свой проект. ВЫ архитектор!) ВЫ творец!) как я градирую - я написал выше)